# Transformação de documento de Venda em Guia de transporte

Tags: vb.net

Na versão 9 ao transformar documento de venda em guia de transporte é despoletado o erro:

> Automation Error

Se usar o mesmo código para outro tipo de documento que não seja guia funciona correctamente.

Segue o código:

```
Public Shared Function transformaDocGrid(ByVal motorPrimavera As ErpBS, tipo As String, numdoc As Long, serie As String)
        Dim docOrigem As GcpBEDocumentoVenda
        Dim docDestino As GcpBEDocumentoVenda
        docDestino = New GcpBEDocumentoVenda
        Dim lngI As Long
        Dim arrDocumentos(0) As Object
        Dim i As Long
        Dim strAvisos As String
        docOrigem = motorPrimavera.Comercial.Vendas.Edita("000", tipo, serie, numdoc)
        With docDestino
            .Tipodoc = "GT"
            .Serie = "2019"
            .Entidade = docOrigem.Entidade
            .TipoEntidade = docOrigem.TipoEntidade
            .Morada = docOrigem.Morada
            .Morada2 = docOrigem.Morada2
            .Localidade = docOrigem.Localidade
            .LocalidadeCodigoPostal = docOrigem.LocalidadeCodigoPostal
            .CodigoPostal = docOrigem.CodigoPostal
            .DataDoc = Now
            .TipoEntidade = docOrigem.TipoEntidade
        End With
        motorPrimavera.Comercial.Vendas.PreencheDadosRelacionados(docDestino, PreencheDados.enuDadosTodos)
        For i = 1 To docOrigem.Linhas.NumItens
                docOrigem.Linhas(i).QuantReservada = 0
            Next
            motorPrimavera.Comercial.Vendas.Actualiza(docOrigem)
        arrDocumentos(0) = docOrigem
        motorPrimavera.Comercial.Vendas.TransformaDocumentoEX(arrDocumentos, docDestino, True, strAvisos)
        docDestino = motorPrimavera.Comercial.Vendas.EditaID(docDestino.ID)
        For i = 1 To docDestino.Linhas.NumItens
                docDestino.Linhas(i).QuantReservada = docDestino.Linhas(i).Quantidade
            Next
        motorPrimavera.Comercial.Vendas.Actualiza(docDestino)
    End Function
```

Comment: Olá André, normalmente este erro acontece quando uma das dlls do erp não está corretamente registada, podes sempre tentar verificar isso com uma aplicação que te faça o clean do registry. Quanto ao código, testei e funciona sem problema.

Comment: Subscrevo o @Daniel Vieira. Já recebi o mesmo erro que após imensas pesquisas e testes revelou-se como um mau registo de uma DLL referente ao ERP.

Comment: Já ficou resolvido!!Obrigado